# How to cite a dictionary entry

Tags: bibtex, citing

What is the recommended BibTeX way to cite a single entry inside a dictionary?

I do not want to cite a dictionary in its entirety, I want to point to a single entry in that dictionary. (Answers to questions like [Citing a dictionary with BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42096/citing-a-dictionary-with-bibtex) deal with the whole dictionary, I want to cite a single entry.)

For example, I would like to cite the entry "*Élégie*" from the dictionary "*Le Dictionnaire Historique de la langue française*" (page 349), published by Le Robert.

Which BibTex entry type should I use to store this in my `.bib` file? Which field for the lemma?

Comment: [Citing a dictionary with BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42096/citing-a-dictionary-with-bibtex) and maybe use the `note`-field for additional information?

Comment: This depends on what style guide you are using for citation format.

Comment: You can use `@reference` for that what you asked. But this entry type is native in `biblatex`, is an alias for `@collection` I'm not sure if it's able in `bibtex`

Comment: Think of "Under the Bridge with Dick and Harry" as a collection of short stories.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the `incollection` bib type.

```
@incollection{Robert,
        Address = {Paris},
        Booktitle = {Le Dictionnaire Historique de la langue française},
        Pages = {349},
        Publisher = {Le Robert},
        Title = {Élégie},
        Year = {1990}}
```

Here's an example using the `kluwer` bibliography style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Robert,
    Address = {Paris},
    Booktitle = {Le Dictionnaire Historique de la langue fran{\c c}aise},
    Pages = {349},
    Publisher = {Le Robert},
    Title = {{\' E}l{\' e}gie},
    Year = {1990}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{kluwer}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Robert}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]